# Movie with character name in title/weird creatures with female leader

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'll give you what I know for sure about it (which isn't a lot) and what could possibly be true to help you figure it out.

For sure stuff: 
The name of the main character is in the title of the movie, most likely ending the title

There are these weird creatures, with a lady as the "leader", who are disguised as humans.

Additional Help:
I saw this 1-2 years ago on Netflix

His name is generic, like John or something

The title could possibly have "of" before the guy's name (Something something of [Insert Character Name Here])

My friend remembers something about him dying over and over, and he can't figure out how to stop dying (something the creatures did to him, more specifically the leader?). Could be something to do with a drug he took/takes, although I'm not quite sure on that. If there is something to do with a drug, it might be a black liquid.

The "leader" interacts with the main character at some point near the beginning, possibly to try and get him to help her do something

There's a scene in the beginning where he gets up from his bed, with his girlfriend/wife in bed with him, and goes into the kitchen to (make breakfast?). The layout of the house is very open, so you can see the living room from the kitchen.

This is all I could remember (might be a lot compared to some other's). It doesn't look like it's on Netflix anymore (I searched the Horror, Sci-Fi & Fantasy, and Thrillers complete lists on their website). Many thanks if you do find it! I've been searching for it for a long time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like [The Deaths of Ian Stone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0810823/), (2007):

> Ian Stone (Mike Vogel) is a working stiff, an American businessman who
>   travels to England for business only to find himself trapped in a
>   bizarre reality: every day he dies a horrific death at the hands of an
>   unknown killer... only to wake up and murdered again and again.

It was one of 2007's "8 Films To Die For".  The leader of the creatures, Medea, was played by Jaime Murray from "Dexter" and "Defiance", who I always mistook for Lena Headey.